# How to convert huge numbers of boost multiprecision (cpp_bin_float) efficiently?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-multiprecision

I have an "extented double" data-type that stores the exponent in a seperate int variable to increase the range like this:

```
struct extDouble
{
    double Value;
    int Exponent;
}
```

I now need to convert a boost multiprecision float (cpp_bin_float) into this data-type. For values within the range of doubles this is no problem and can be done with

```
extDouble Number;
Number.Value = BigNumber.convert_to<double>();
Number.Exponent = 0;
```

(the loss of decimal places is no problem).

But how could I (efficiently) do this with values beyond the range of doubles? I know I could read the exponent directly like this:

```
Number.Exponent = BigNumber.backend().exponent();
```

But in order to get the fractional value, I would have to multiply `BigNumber` by `pow(2, Exponent)` which I want to avoid for performance reasons. Is there a way to read out the fractional value directly or simply set the exponent of `BigNumber` to 0? Or does anybody have another idea how to accomplish the whole thing as efficiently as possible (something like frexp or ldexp for boost multiprecision)?

**Edit:**

To clarify: if there was `frexp` for boost multifloats, I would simply do something like this:

```
Number.Value = frexp(BigNumber, &Number.Exponent);
```

Comment: *But how could I (efficiently) do this with values beyond the range of doubles?* -- Has your testing proven that this is not efficient?

Comment: How would I do this BEYOND the range of doubles (so exponents >324 or <-324 or so)? .convert_to<double> should give inf or 0 then, shouldn't it?

Comment: What is the base for the exponent? Assuming 2 (but maybe you imply 10?)

Comment: The base in "extDouble" would be 2. I'm not sure what boost uses...

Comment: @PaulAner it (obviously) uses 2, because it's a _binary_ floating point backend. I'll post an answer somewhere tonight.

Comment: Oh that was simple. Always check your assumptions :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought I was going to post a clever answer based in `ilogb`/`scalbn`¹, but then I thought to just check the premise:

```
extDouble toExt(F number) {
    extDouble n;
    n.Value = frexp(number, &n.Exponent).convert_to<double>();
    return n;
}
```

Works just fine. `frexp` is found via ADL, and resolves to the multiprecision implementation.

Generalized a bit and with test cases:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dbaefd341458baf5)**

```
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_bin_float.hpp>
using F = boost::multiprecision::cpp_bin_float_50;

struct extDouble {
    double Value;
    int Exponent;

    friend auto& operator<<(std::ostream& os, extDouble const& ed) {
        return os << "{Value:" << ed.Value << ", Exponent:" << ed.Exponent << "}";
    }
};

template <typename F> extDouble toExt(F number) {
    extDouble n;
    n.Value = frexp(number, &n.Exponent).template convert_to<double>();
    return n;
}

int main() {
    using L = std::numeric_limits<double>;
    std::cout << "max exponent: " << L::max_exponent << "\n";
    std::cout << "mix exponent: " << L::min_exponent << "\n";

    for (F f :
         {
             F("123.45"),
             F("123.45") * pow(F(2), L::max_exponent - 5),
             F("123.45") * pow(F(2), L::min_exponent + 3),
             F("123.45") * pow(F(2), L::max_exponent * 2),
             F("123.45") * pow(F(2), L::min_exponent * 2),
         }) //
    {
        std::cout << f << " -> " << toExt(f) << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Prints

```
max exponent: 1024
mix exponent: -1021
123.45 -> {Value:0.964453, Exponent:7}
6.93516e+308 -> {Value:0.964453, Exponent:1026}
4.39497e-305 -> {Value:0.964453, Exponent:-1011}
3.98953e+618 -> {Value:0.964453, Exponent:2055}
2.44478e-613 -> {Value:0.964453, Exponent:-2035}
```

---

¹ much like here https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/frexp

Comment: OK, that was really simple. I have even searched for "boost frexp" and didn't find anything. Thanks, sehe